# Gradle shadow: how to include some package

Tags: java, gradle, include, shadow, minimize

I have this dependency, I want to include this in the jar without minimizing it.
[image]

But that will exclude some important classes.
So I tried to use include dependency.
[image]

But that will include all the classes.

How can I use the custom filter with code?

Or include special packages of dependency in the jar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are no default options to include partial set of classes from a jar (dependency).

The 2 options you have are

1. if this is a 'rarely' changing set of classes
   manually create a custom jar with the classes you need, save it local to project or in nexus and use it in the include
2. if this is a 'often' changing set of classes
   create a task, before jar and after classes, to extract the classes you need in to the build/../classes folder